# Scala Play load partial template by String name

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, template-engine

I have a Scala template like this...

```
@()
import view.html.partials._header
import view.html.partials._footer

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    @_header()

    /* Body of web page */

    @_footer

</html>
```

Every single page has the same header and footer and a different body. I do not want to do this...

Page #1...

```
@()
import view.html.partials._header
import view.html.partials._footer
import view.html.partials._body1

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    @_header()
    @_body1()
    @_footer
</html>
```

Page #2...

```
@()
import view.html.partials._header
import view.html.partials._footer
import view.html.partials._body2

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    @_header()
    @_body2()
    @_footer
</html>
```

Page #3...

```
@()
import view.html.partials._header
import view.html.partials._footer
import view.html.partials._body3

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    @_header()
    @_body3()
    @_footer
</html>
```

Etc.

Is there a way to pass in the name of the partial template you want to render as a parameter? What is the solution to this problem?

p.s. I don't see the solution in... [the play template documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having all these repetitions, you can create a `main.scala.html` file to be used as a default layout:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

@import view.html.partials._header
@import view.html.partials._footer

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    @_header()

    <body>

        @content

        @_footer()

    </body>
</html>
```

The first line says exactly "this view will receive a title argument and also a block of HTML". From that, you can do the following:

Page #1:

```
@(someParameter: String)

@main("The title of Page #1") {

    <h1>Hello, I'm the body of Page #1</h1>

    <p>As you can see, I'm calling the main view passing 
       a title and a block of HTML</p>

}
```

Page #2:

```
@(someParameter: String, anotherParameter: Long)

@main("This time Page #2") {

    <h1>Hello, I'm the body of Page #2</h1>

    <p>Just like Page #1, I'm passing a title
       and a block of HTML to the main view.</p>

}
```

This is all explained at the docs, but in another page:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplateUseCases

Answer (score -1):

Make a switch or case statement like this...

```
@(bodyCase: ClosedEnumType)

import view.html.partials._header
import view.html.partials._footer
import view.html.partials._body1
import view.html.partials._body2

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    @_header()

    @bodyCase match {
      case Body1() => {
          @_body1()
      }
      case Body2() => {
          @_body2()
      }
    }

    @_footer

</html>
```

Comment: You're going to be much happier with the other answer.  The approach you've is very much going against the framework.